# Evento clic para imprimir lo que hay dentro del script JS

Tags: javascript, html

Como puedo hacer para al darle click en el boton probar me imprima lo que hay dentro del script.

Esto es lo que he intentado:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

<script>
var miArray = [ 10, 20, 40, 65 ];
var miArray2= [15, 26, 44, 71];
var miArray3 = ["TaT","Pan","Aut","Caf"];

for (var i=0; i<miArray.length; i++) {  
for (var j=miArray[i]; j<=miArray2[i]; j++) {
var mostrar = j + " "+miArray3[i];
}
}

</script>

<button onclick="mostar;">Probar</button>


</body>
```

Comment: A que te refieres con imprimir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es escribir el resultado en el browser puedes hacerlo asi:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

<script>
function mostrar() {
var miArray = [ 10, 20, 40, 65 ];
var miArray2= [15, 26, 44, 71];
var miArray3 = ["TaT","Pan","Aut","Caf"];
var mostrar = "";
for (var i=0; i<miArray.length; i++) {  
for (var j=miArray[i]; j<=miArray2[i]; j++) {
 mostrar += j + " "+miArray3[i];
}
}
document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = mostrar;
}
</script>

<button onclick="mostrar();">Probar</button>
<div id="resultado"></div>

</body>
```